# Conditional SSIS - execute one task or another based on the result

Tags: sql-server, ssis, expression, etl, operator-precedence

I have the following tasks in SSIS:

[image]

In Check Stock task, I execute a stored procedure which returns 0 or 1:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_CheckStockAvailability]
AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @ItemGID nvarchar(250)=(SELECT TOP (1) ItemGID FROM XMLOrderlines WHERE Comparison='0')

SELECT CASE 
WHEN @ItemGID IS NOT NULL
THEN CAST (0 AS bit)
ELSE CAST (1 AS bit)
END AS Comparison
FROM XMLOrderlines 

END
GO
```

I would like to execute Reject Order (on the right) task if the result is 1 and, if not, to execute the one from the left. I set to export the result of the procedure in a variable, `Boolean` data type with a default value of "False".

If I edit the precedence constraint and I set `Expression` as evaluation operation and then choose the variable from the previous task, either way it does not go to the next task that is supposed to. What am I missing? I tried what I found on the web but nothing helped me. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

You have to set the following values:

*Reject Order*

```
Evaluation operation:   Expression and Constraint
Value:                  Success
Expression:             @[User::Result] = 1
                     OR 
                        @[User::Result]
```

*Accept Order*

```
Evaluation operation:   Expression and Constraint
Value:                  Success
Expression:             @[User::Result] = 0 
                     OR 
                        !@[User::Result]
```

*Screenshot*

[image]

## Suggestions

I think it is better to add a `TRY...CATCH` block to your procedure, so if it encounters an error the result will be `1` and the Order is rejected:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_CheckStockAvailability]
AS

    BEGIN

    BEGIN TRY  

        DECLARE @ItemGID nvarchar(250)=(SELECT TOP (1) ItemGID FROM XMLOrderlines WHERE Comparison='0')

        SELECT CASE 
        WHEN @ItemGID IS NOT NULL
        THEN CAST (0 AS bit)
        ELSE CAST (1 AS bit)
        END AS Comparison
        FROM XMLOrderlines 

    END TRY 
    BEGIN CATCH

        SELECT 1 AS Comparison

    END CATCH

    END
GO
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. The point is that my stored procedure will never fail and I cannot set on a precedence constraint to execute a certain step if it is a failure. What should I do in this case?

Comment: This will change nothing. Even if it is always success

Answer (score 2):

Try choosing *Evaluation Operation* to *Expression and Constraint* and the expression has to be smth like `@[User::Result] = 1`. The expression has to return `True` or `False`.

For more informations, follow this link:

- [Working with Precedence Constraints in SQL Server Integration Services](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/working-with-precedence-constraints-in-sql-server-integration-services/)

Comment: `@[User::Result] == 1` is not a SSIS expression, you have to write `@[User::Result] = 1`

Answer (score 1):

The expression for `1`/`True` should be `@[User::Result]`, as you have, and the expression for `0`/`False` should be `!@[User::Result]` (notice the exclamation mark).

You may also want to look into using "Expression and Constraint" as an "Evaluation operation", as without that, the flow will continue regardless of whether "Check stock" succeeds or fails (unless that is the desired behaviour). The "Constraint" part of this is what the "Value" field represents - in your image it is set to `Failure`, but greyed out (due to having only "Expression" selected) and therefore inactive.

Comment: On the value filed, should I use Success for both?

Comment: the query in "Check Stock" will always succeed. How should I do in this case?

Comment: Yeah, use "Success" for both - this really just ensures that if you get some random error - someone changes a table name, something like that - the process will stop and you'll get error messages, etc., and the process won't go any further. So yeah, I'd use "Success" and then the expressions I've posted.

Comment: "Success" is the default, every new constraint you draw will have that "Value". It's actually confusing that the arrow will stay green if you use "Expression" only - it should really be black, signifying "Completion", which means the flow will proceed either way (success/failure).